# finding an omitted conjunction

Tags: grammar

I was wondering whether a relative adverb 'when' is omitted or a conjunction 'that' notifying starting a noun clause is omitted in the below sentence. If a 'that' leading a noun clause is omitted, is the clause followed by the 'that' in apposition with "a sixth time"?

The sentence comes in NBC Nightly News:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XkmFR1YGADA&t=266s

> Today marks a sixth time this year **(when/that/where/..)** the Fed has hiked
> interest rates, adding another three quarters of a percent today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>Normally nothing would go in that location. I would consider the nominal phrase "this year" to function as a modifier, modifying the direct object "a sixth time".</s>

If you must put something in that location, then you could try the preposition "during" (making "sixth year" its object). However, few people would actually say or write that.

---

Update based on edited question:

Yes, your instinct is correct. In theory, we could introduce the relative clause with a preposition and a relative pronoun:

> Today marks a sixth time this year **during which** the Fed has hiked interest rates, adding another three quarters of a percent today.

However, that is very rare in practice. (The preposition "during" doesn't really have the correct meaning there.) Most people would instead use "when" or "that". I would recommend against using "where" since the meaning is more temporal than spatial, but it is occasionally used in such situations.

If you used "that", then I wouldn't consider the subordinate clause to be an appositive, because a "that" clause usually represents a fact and not a time. (For example, "I know **that you are happy**" means that I know a particular fact.) Whether you used "when" or "that", I'd consider it a relative (adjectival) clause, since it describes the nominal phrase "a sixth time".

Comment: Sorry, I tweaked my question, and please look it over again.